# running multiple jobs from a batch file in pentaho

Tags: batch-file, pentaho, jobs, kettle

I would like to ask if there is a more efficient way of running multiple transformations(70 transformations) besides the IDE? Doing it the IDE way is alright but it does become tedious having to click all the tabs and the hidden tabs as well.

What I did was I tried using the pan.bat command and placed it in a bat file. The bat file would look like this:

```
cd <to dest of kitchen.bat>

pan.bat <mytransformation 1>
pan.bat <mytransformation 2>
pan.bat <mytransformation 3>
pan.bat <mytransformation 4>
```

But it only works on the first transformation and then it quits. Am I doing something wrong or what options do I have to run multuple transformations from script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When calling a batch file from another, you have to use the `call` command, otherwise (as you found) it transfers control to the new batch file permanently.

```
call pan.bat <mytransformation 1>
call pan.bat <mytransformation 2>
call pan.bat <mytransformation 3>
call pan.bat <mytransformation 4>
```

Answer (score 7):

Thats what a JOB is for. Create a Job (or jobs) to run these transformations and execute with kitchen not pan.

You can also dynamically execute KTR's if you want to as well.  i.e. execute all KTRs in a given folder etc.

Running via a job should be marginally faster too as you're not starting and stopping the entire VM every time.  (which is surprisingly expensive)

Additionally running via a job gives you control over error handling, parallelisation and sequencing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
pan.bat "mytransformation 1"
```

.. or:

```
start /b "" "pan.bat" "mytransformation 1"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine all transformations as a single or 2 jobs then call the job this is a efficiency way to call the all transformations in single job.

In pentaho by default jobs are running sequence mode if you want run parallel mode you can easily